# How to selected option in listbox by value

Tags: jquery, select

I populate a list box with jquery after that i want to select a option dynamically by value. But i havent successed.

Here is list

At page load populate list

```
    function getOpenBilllist() {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "businessLounge.aspx/getOpenBillList",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var openbillList = $('.openBill');
                    openbillList.empty();
                    $.each(r.d, function () {
                        openbillList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Script: this method add the article in the bill and getOpenBilllist(); method re-populate the list to get latest list of open bills.

```
    function addArticleToBill(articleID) {
        $(function () {
            var uid = $("#<% = uID.ClientID %>").val();
            var contactPersonID = getContactPersonID();
            if (typeof contactPersonID == "undefined") {
                alert("Please Select Contact Person");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "businessLounge.aspx/addArticleInBill",
                    data: "{'articleID':'" + articleID + "','contactPersonID':'" + contactPersonID + "','uid':'" + uid + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        getBill(contactPersonID, '');
                        getOpenBilllist();
                        $('.openBill').val(contactPersonID);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Problem:

In success after re-populate the list i want to select the option in the list $('.openBill').val(contactPersonID); but option is not selected. Option is in the list. I dont know it not selected by my code. There is no error in debug window as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **$.ajax()** is asynchronous you cannot select the option after calling **getOpenBilllist();**.

Instead, you can pass the value to the function and so select the option there:

```js
/*
function getOpenBilllist(contactPersonID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "businessLounge.aspx/getOpenBillList",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var openbillList = $('.openBill');
            openbillList.empty();
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                openbillList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
            openbillList.val(contactPersonID); // <-------------------
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
*/

var openbillList = $('.openBill');
contactPersonID = 2;
openbillList.empty();
$.each([{Value: 1, Text: 1}, {Value: 2, Text: 2}, {Value: 3, Text: 3}], function () {
    openbillList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
});
$('.openBill').val(contactPersonID);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="openBill"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks its fulfill my requirement :).